# Relative layout on different devices

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have an app which is supposed to work on different layouts of phone and tablets.
On my phone it uses a vertical layout and uses all the screen while on my tablet it stays tiny instead of using the whole screen.
I used a relative layout but referring to fill_parent for widths thinking that this was the right way to use all the parent's space (the whole screen).
Here is my code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:background="#bbbbbb" >

    <!-- Parte1  -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Distanza Km        m         Gare"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
         android:id="@+id/button1"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="50dp"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
         android:onClick="OnClickButton1"
         android:text="@string/calcola" />   

    <EditText
         android:id="@+id/editText1_1"
         android:layout_width="@dimen/single_textEdit"
         android:layout_height="50dp"
         android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
         android:background="#fff123"        
         android:inputType="numberDecimal"
         android:singleLine="true"
         android:textSize="40sp" 
         android:gravity="center" 
         android:imeOptions="actionDone"
         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
         android:nextFocusDown="@+id/editText1_2"
         android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"/>     

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1_2"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/double_textEdit"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="#fff123"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText1_1"        
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:nextFocusDown="@+id/editText2_1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="40sp" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/gare_spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@layout/border"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:dropDownSelector="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText1_2" />
        ....
```

Comment: Create another folder, `res/layout-land` where to put the layouts for the landscape mode.

Comment: Can you post some images for us to understand what you mean?

Comment: did u tried `android:layout_weight` ?

Answer (score 0):

Make a new layout folder. Your normal folder is just called layout, but make a second one called layout-sw600dp. This is for screen width of 600 pixels, so basically for tablets. You can make the exact same xml layouts and just give them different dimensions in here.